# how to call a onload function in xul?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, onload

I understand there's a lot of material on this question, but for some reason, I still can't get my function to run. What am I doing wrong? Below is my xul and js file.

```
    <window id="SCOptionsWindow" title="Options" width="550" onload="SCOWLoadWindow();"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
      <script type="application/x-javascript"
            src="chrome://hi/content/optionsWindow.js" />
    ...

    function SCOWLoadWindow(){
        alert("hi");
    }

    ...
   </script>
```

I don't know why this doesn't work? My other like oncommand work just fine.

Comment: As listed here, this code works fine. The issue must be elsewhere. Try to produce a minimal XUL page showing your issue?

Comment: Is ````SCOWLoadWindow```` function between ````<script>```` and ````</script>````? What I can see from snippet above is that first ````<script>```` tag is self-closed.